# how to scale operator menu (scale_x) wider

Tags: python, interface, operator

EDIT!!

I will rephrase my question
The script I am working on has the same operator menu as you would get when adding a plane. Add > mesh > plane.

No popup or whatsoever. It is a custom drawing,

[image]

Can this operator menu be scales along X axis?

END EDIT!!

Making an addon I'm running into an scaling issue.

I try to scale the operator menu wider (scale_x) but it does not work.

```
    def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.scale_x = 5.0 <-- DOES NOT DO ANYTHING
    layout.scale_x = 5.0 <-- MAKES THE MENU HIGHER NOT WIDER
    #layout.aligment['CENTER']
    #layout.direction['VERTICAL']
    col = layout.column(align=True)
    col.scale_x = 100 <-- Scales column but not the menu itself
    col.label(text="Custom Interface! option2")

    row = col.row(align=True)
    row.scale_x = 250 <-- Scales the row inside the menu but not the menu itself
    row.prop(self, "Row prop")

    col.prop(self, "Column prop")
```

Anyone also experienced this? Is this a bug or is it me?

Comment: scale_x only works inside a layout. to change popup size use width= in context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self, width=500). see: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html?highlight=popup_menu#bpy.types.WindowManager.invoke_popup

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used  <---def invoke(self, context, event): return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self, width=500) --> But this generates a popup and does not change the operator menu itself...

Comment: Anyone who knows how to scale the operator menu or is this not possible?